How to return an error from AppSync lambda resolver?
I am trying to return an error that my (apollo) client can parse, but i am not able to pass even a message from my server (lambda).
I tried to throw a new Error(), i tried to use callback("my error here") as in the official documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-lambda-resolvers.html
I tried to return an object with an "errors" array... But i always get the same result, i get this message in my network payload message (errors[0].message): "Error while de-serializing lambda response payload. Got: "
I didn't find anybody with the same issue, kind of blocked with that since hours now, any help would be really really appreciated!
